# What causes the stairstep structure in bismuth crystals?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

I've been interested in bismuth crystallization since I found out they existed, but have a question on their formation.

According to Wikipedia, the stair-step structure of bismuth crystals is "the result of a higher growth rate around the outside edges than on the inside edges."

What would cause this higher growth rate around the edges? Cooling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hopper crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopper_crystal), that is, the "staircase" form, develop when a crystal forms so rapidly that material is used up before the interior finishes.

[Table salt, $\ce{NaCl}$, also forms nice hopper crystals.](http://lateralscience.blogspot.com/2014/10/nasa-microgravity-hopper-crystals.html) If you want to try this, use "kosher" salt or CP $\ce{NaCl}$, which doesn't have anti-caking and iodide additives that would spoil the crystal structure.